# How to get Partition Names on a PhysicalDrive?

Tags: partition, disk-partitioning

I am trying to get the names of partitions residing on a PhysicalDrive. I can't find any Win32 API function to do this.
I've tried every IOCTL I could find but none gave any useful results.

I can open each PhysicalDrive sucessfully but don't know what to do with the handle in order to get the partition name.